# View documents without folders

Tags: document-library, error, view, folder

I've inherited a document library with some documents stored in folders within folders within folders etc

I've tried creating a library view with "Show all items without folders"  but I get the following error

```
This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator.
```

I need to move some of the documents to a new library. There is no metadata that would help show only the documents I need other than "Created By". I tried adding this as a filter to the view but I still get the same error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set item limit < 5000 to view of the document library.

Or this link might help you,

[Overcoming ~5000 File Document Library Limits](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105937/overcoming-5000-file-document-library-limits)